# Why does Apple define UInt32 as long or int depending on platform?

Tags: c, macos-carbon

I noticed that UInt32 is defined differently based on the platform in [MacTypes.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacTypes.h)

```
#if __LP64__
typedef unsigned int                    UInt32;
typedef signed int                      SInt32;
#else
typedef unsigned long                   UInt32;
typedef signed long                     SInt32;
#endif
```

If `unsigned int` is always 32 bits on 32 and 64bit machines, why do they bother conditionally checking the platform?

Comment: Similar issue: `NSInteger` is `int` in 32-bit mode and `long` in 64-bit mode. If Apple had defined `NSInteger` as `long` generally then we would not have to add casts for every printf statement.

Comment: Perhaps the `else` case also supports systems with 16-bit `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it is some old code which was initially:

```
typedef unsigned long                   UInt32;
typedef signed long                     SInt32;
```

and a developper later added the LP64 and he did by adding the lines:

```
#if __LP64__
typedef unsigned int                    UInt32;
typedef signed int                      SInt32;
#else
```

to no impact the previous platforms.

Of course, it does not make much sense to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The type `UInt32` existed before 64-bit support. It has historically been defined as `unsigned long`. It could have been `unsigned int`. I don't know why `long` was chosen over `int` at that time. The choice would have been largely arbitrary.

Once that choice was made, though, it can't be changed, even though `unsigned int` would work for both 32- and 64-bit.

The big thing that would break if it were changed would be C++. In C++, the types of arguments are baked into the symbol names in the object files and libraries. `long` and `int` are different types, so `void foo(long);` and `void foo(int);` are separate functions with separate symbol names. If `UInt32` were to change in 32-bit, then you wouldn't be able to link against libraries that were built with the old definition. If the libraries were rebuilt with the new definition, then old compiled code would not be able to load them.

Answer (score 1):

A `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits. An `int` will be 16 bits on a 16 bit processor. This is discussed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types, among other places.

Comment: All (current) Apple platforms (OS X and iOS) use the ILP32 data model in 32-bit mode, and LP64 in 64-bit mode. So in the context of "MacTypes.h", an int is always 32 bit, and a long is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: All current platforms, yes. http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacTypes.h But back in 1985 (see the copyright), there were no 32-bit or 64-bit Macs.

Comment: (And no iOS :-) - So that is the reason for `typedef signed long SInt32` in "non-64-bit-mode", that makes sense.

Comment: @Pete first Macintosh was released in 1984 with the Motorola 68000 (a 16/32-bit). As far as I know most C compilers at the time had a 32-bit `int` for the 68000 (for example Lattice C compiler for 68000).

Comment: The first Mac had a 16-bit data bus. I would expect that would mean a 16-bit `int`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Pete Lattice is not the best example as it was apparently running on a few 68k plaftforms (Amiga, MS-DOS, Sun) but non on Mac. It could be interesting to check with the popular Mac compilers at the time.

Comment: According to this (http://pastebin.com/nhey7Lw4) and a few other places I've seen, MacOS was LP32, which has a 16-bit `int`

Comment: @Peter for info Metrowerks CW for 68k Macintosh support 2 or 4 bytes `int` and default is 4 bytes. See http://faculty.petra.ac.id/indi/files/C++%20and%20Assembly%20Language%20Reference.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The actual size of integer types varies by implementation. The standard only requires size relations between the data types and minimum sizes for each data type.  Generally, the sizeof(int) reflects that "natural/native" size of the machine.  On a 64-bit machine, int might be defined as 32 or 64 bits, ; 32-bits on 32-bit architecture, 16-bit on 16-bit machines.  However, the standard indicates that int type will always be at least 16 bits.

Comment: `int` is commonly 32 bits even on 64-bit machines (likely because making `int` 64 bits makes it difficult to have predefined 8-, 16-, and 32-bit integer types). And the standard doesn't just "suggest" that `int` is at least 16 bits, it absolutely requires it.

Comment: @KeithThompson, you are absolutely correct.  I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: This still doesn't really answer the question. Since `int` is consistently 32 bits on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms (at least those for which `MacTypes.h` is currently relevant), it *could* have unconditionally defined `UInt32` as `unsigned int` and `SInt32` as `int`. Apparently the reasons are historical, as discussed in other answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned int` is **not** always 32-bit long, it depends on the model

- In LP64 model, long and pointer are 64-bit types, int is a 32-bit type
- In ILP64 model, int, long and pointer are 64-bit types

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

In other models, `int` can have any other number of bits. The only restriction is that it must have at least 16 bits