# Why isn't NSInteger defined as long on 32-bit iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

`NSInteger` is defined this way:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

This results in `NSInteger` being defined as int on 32-bit iOS even though int and long are the same anyway (both 4 bytes). Format strings like the following generate a warning with this definition:

```
NSInteger x = 4;
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", x];

// Warning: Values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments;
// add an explicit cast to 'long' instead.
```

So does somebody know why `NSInteger` isn't always defined as long?

Comment: OSX and iOS both uses same foundation framework. Hence they have different variants.

Comment: Mostly it's because you should never have a C-based language without confusion about integer sizes.  It's against the law.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of format string problems, try @(x).stringValue or [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(x)] - future proof :)

Comment: The entire point of `NSInteger` is to use whatever integer is "native" for the current hardware. You use it when you don't really care if it's 32 or 64 bit. Since Mac OS X cannot run on 32 bit processors, it is always 64 bit, but iOS runs on both 32 and 64 so it will be one or the other.

Comment: Yes, but my questions was why not always use long for NSInteger. long is always native/pointer size (4 bytes on 32 bit iOS and 8 bytes on 64 bit iOS/OSX).

Comment: @lassej because long needs to be compatible with C/C++ code written for Windows/Linux, while NSInteger only exists on iOS/OS X which means Apple can change their mind about it's size whenever they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historical reasons, where previous releases of APIs used `int` -- then were migrated to use `typedef NSInteger` ca. the 64-bit transition of OS X.

I suppose they could have changed for iOS, but that would have impacted a lot of existing and to-be-developed code if they were different on OS X and iOS.

Comment: Some historical reasons are mentioned in the comments to the similar question [Why does Apple define UInt32 as long or int depending on platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503088/why-does-apple-define-uint32-as-long-or-int-depending-on-platform).